# Bus 001 Device 003: ID 13b1:003a Linksys AE2500 802.11abgn Wireless Adapter [Broadcom BCM43236] driver

Tags: wireless, drivers

Does anyone know how exactly to get the driver installed for this and give a step by step guide? Everything I've tried so far goes to a dead end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The device only works with ndiswrapper. With a temporary working interet connection by ethernet or any other means, open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt-get install ndiswrapper-common ndiswrapper-utils-1.9
```

Download the driver file to your desktop here: http://downloads.linksys.com/downloads/driver/AE2500xp_WHQL,0.zip Right-click it and select 'Extract Here.'

Find out if you need the 32- or 64-bit files:

```
arch
```

64-bit returns *x86_64*. If yours is a 64-bit system, you will need to make an edit to the driver file. Open "bcmwlhigh5.inf" in gedit or any text editor and add this line, around line 170:

```
[Linksys_AE2500.files.NTamd64]
  AE2500xp64.sys,,,6
```

Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor. Now do:

```
cd ~/Desktop/xp
sudo ndiswrapper -i bcmwlhigh5.inf
sudo ndiswrapper -ma
sudo depmod -a
```

Reboot. If the wireless is not working, see if you can see any problems:

```
ndiswrapper -l
```

That's a lower-case L for 'list,' not the number 1. Also:

```
dmesg | grep ndis
```

Comment: It didn't work. The sudo depmod command was supposed to return something in the terminal, right? Every thing else did before it except that.

Comment: When I tried it again, it said it couldn't find section "Linksys_AE1200.files.NTamd64" even though that's not the adapter I'm using. Then when I tried it again, it said the driver was already installed. And the last command still doesn't return anything if it's supposed to.

Comment: And also, do you edit line 170 that has the 32 bit for AE2500 or do you add that whole to the document.  I did the latter. I noticed that it has the 32 bit part for it twice. Was that so it might be edited for 64 bit?

Comment: One thing I did differently from this was that I already had a ndiswrapper 1.59 folder installed and extracted and the terminal gives an error on the bcmwlhigh5.inf command unless I moved that folder to the desktop. Should I just delete everything and try again? It's not like having these folder saved is doing much good right now anyway.

Comment: Is yours a 32- or 64-bit system? If 32-bit, you need do no edits at all.

Comment: It's 64 bit. Is the last command supposed to return something in the terminal?

Comment: Do you mean: `sudo depmod -a`? No; if it completes with no error or warning, no output will return.

Comment: Do you know what could be going wrong, then?

Comment: Please see my edit above.

Comment: The first command from your edit said the driver was installed and the second command didn't return anything. I still can't use it. DO I have to reboot after doing the second command?

Comment: Please try: `sudo modprobe ndiswrapper` and then: `dmesg | grep ndis` Thanks.

Comment: It said it updated ndiswrapper, but my adapter's still not being detected.

Comment: I'd like to see the exact output of `dmesg | grep ndis` please. Can you copy and paste it to a text file,  transfer it on a USB and post it please?

Comment: It doesn't give an output. The terminal doesn't do anything for a few seconds, then it just starts a new line as if I pressed enter without typing anything.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23621/discussion-between-chili555-and-bighippo).

Comment: It messed up again and then started working again. When I did one of the commands, it said "missing parameters see -h" What does that mean?

Comment: Which command??

Comment: It does it for 'sudo modprobe -v' and says "modprobe: ERROR: missing parameters. See -h."

Comment: Turns out I forgot the "nidswrapper" part in the "sudo modprobe -v" command. Then when I did "dmesg | grep ndis" I got this a message too long to show in this comment.

Comment: Really helpful answer. But on my Ubuntu 16.04.1, I couldn't select any displayed wireless network (greyed out). I needed to add to the end of `/etc/modules` (with `sudoedit /etc/modules`) the following line:
`ndiswrapper`, then reboot. @chili555 I don't know why you rejected my edit, but it could be useful for other users.

Comment: AFAIK, the command `sudo ndiswrapper -ma` creates the alias. I am surprised that it doesn't work for you. Until we see more data, your edit seems specific to your case only.

Answer (score -1):

```
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
```

then run

```
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer b43-fwcutter
```

Remove from blacklist if found.

check the file /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf

if it contains an entry for bcm4* then put # to comment it or remove the whole line.

also notice if there is a file called bcm4* under the directory /etc/modprobe.d/ then remove it.

Now run the command:

```
sudo modprobe -r b43
sudo modprobe b43    
sudo rfkill unblock all
```

Comment: This method is incorrect. The b43 and ssb driver suite do not drive any USB device.