# AE2500 802.11abgn Wireless Adapter [Broadcom BCM43236] Not finding 5ghz Wifi Network.

Tags: networking, drivers, usb, broadcom

I have installed the AE2500 Linksys adapter with very few problems. However, the adapter is not finding the 5ghz side of the network. That defeats the whole purpose of me buying this stick, so here is what I did from this link. [Bus 001 Device 003: ID 13b1:003a Linksys AE2500 802.11abgn Wireless Adapter [Broadcom BCM43236] driver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/620988/bus-001-device-003-id-13b1003a-linksys-ae2500-802-11abgn-wireless-adapter-bro)

```
bcmwlhigh8 : driver installed
    device (13B1:003A) present
```

It said bcmwlhigh8 because I had to rename the .inf file.

Btw this is my usb drive under lsusb.

```
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 13b1:003a Linksys AE2500 802.11abgn Wireless Adapter [Broadcom BCM43236]
```

It connects to my 2.4 ghz network just fine, but not the 5ghz..

What can I do about this?

Comment: Do you have a dual-band router? Cheers, Al

Comment: yes it is. my phone can see it.

Comment: My experience with ndiswrapper is that it doesn't work very well, and should only be used as a last resort, and only to get the barest hardware working. In the link that you provide above, did you try the second answer provided by @Maythux? It's a much better way to go. I'd **remove ndiswrapper** and try his. Cheers, Al

Comment: Just got done, and restarted my computer. It didn't work. I'm still using my backup usb stick.

Comment: Nope. It Didn't work.. Unless I'm messing it up, but I I'm not sure what else I can do.

Comment: Doesn't work at ALL, or doesn't see 5ghz? Did you comment out **blacklist bcm43xx** in **/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf**, as per the instructions, and the remaining three commands, and reboot? Cheers, Al

Comment: Doesn't work at all.. Like there is no stick.

Comment: You didn't answer my questions about following the remainder of the instructions. Any way, you might try "Googling" `device id 13b1:003a` and you'll find a ton of hits with people with the same problem as yourself. I briefly read one that was 13 pages long! So, the short of it, if you can't find any good info that way, you might just get yourself another adapter that's easier to get going. Cheers, Al

Comment: This link makes it clear. It looks like I will need a new adapter http://askubuntu.com/questions/664094/cant-connect-to-wifi-5ghz-with-broadcom-corporation-bcm4311